# Obtener el nombre completo de una propiedad

Tags: c#, .net, linq, genericos

Estoy trabajando en C#, usando [Linq Dynamic](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic/) para realizar algunos ordenamientos, por lo cual se me generó la necesidad de obtener los nombres de las propiedades como `string`.

Cuando las propiedades son simples, no me generan ningún conflicto, ya que puedo usar `nameof()` perfectamente.

Mi problema se da al obtener los nombres de las propiedades hijas de objetos.

Planteo un ejemplo para que se interprete

```
public class Padre
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public Hijo H { get; set; }
}

public class Hijo
{
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
}
```

Al querer acceder al nombre de `Prop1`, lo puedo hacer perfectamente como `nameof(Prop1)`.

El problema se da al querer obtener el nombre de `Prop2` dentro de una instancia de `Padre`, por ejemplo

```
Padre p = new Padre();
string nombreProp2 = nameof(p.H.Prop2);
```

Donde pretendo obtener el string `"H.Prop2"` pero obtengo solo `Prop2`, actualmente obtengo el valor de manera manual haciendo algo como

```
string nombreProp2 = string.Format("{0}.{1}",nameof(p.H),nameof(p.H.Prop2))
```

Existe algún método más directo de obtener este dato?

Comment: Para obtener eso has de hacer un metodo en reflection que te permita obtener el nombre de las diferente propiedades y sus subpropiedades, [propertyInfo](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: puedes usar expresiones lambda

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Espero te sirva:

```
public static class ExpressionHelper
{
    public static string PathOf<T>(this T @object, Expression<Func<T, object>> expression)
    {
        return PathOf<T>(expression);
    }  

    static string PathOf<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> expr)
    {
        MemberExpression memberExpression;

        switch (expr.Body.NodeType) {
            case ExpressionType.Convert:
            case ExpressionType.ConvertChecked:
                var unaryExpression = expr.Body as UnaryExpression;
                memberExpression = ((unaryExpression != null) ? unaryExpression.Operand : null) as MemberExpression;
                break;
            default:
                memberExpression = expr.Body as MemberExpression;
                break;
        }

        var path = string.Empty;
        while (memberExpression != null) {
            string propertyName = memberExpression.Member.Name;
            path += "." + propertyName;
            memberExpression = memberExpression.Expression as MemberExpression;
        }

        return path.Substring(path.IndexOf('.') + 1);
    }  
}
```

Y la usas:

```
var p = new Padre();
var nombreProp2 = p.PathOf(x => x.H.Prop2);
```

Y el resultado sería "H.Prop2".